# Resolving code analysis warnings with the BOLDDAY macro (used with CMonthCalCtrl)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, code-analysis, monthcalendar

I have some issues with the [`CMonthCalCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmonthcalctrl-class?view=msvc-160) control and modernizing my code. The first problem is related to the `BOLDDAY` macro.

This macro is used to adjust **day states** (making specific dates **bold** on the calendar) and the concept is described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/set-day-states). As documented, you need to define a macro:

```
#define  BOLDDAY(ds, iDay) if(iDay > 0 && iDay < 32) \
            (ds) |= (0x00000001 << (iDay-1))
```

Here is my code that uses this macro so that you have some context:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::InitDayStateArray(int iMonthCount, LPMONTHDAYSTATE pDayState, COleDateTime datStart)
{
    int                 iMonth = 0;
    COleDateTimeSpan    spnDay;
    CString             strKey;
    SPECIAL_EVENT_S     *psEvent = nullptr;

    if (pDayState == nullptr)
        return;

    memset(pDayState, 0, sizeof(MONTHDAYSTATE)*iMonthCount);

    if (m_pMapSPtrEvents == nullptr && m_Reminders.Count() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    spnDay.SetDateTimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);

    auto datDay = datStart;
    const auto iStartMonth = datStart.GetMonth();
    auto iThisMonth = iStartMonth;
    auto iLastMonth = iThisMonth;
    do
    {
        strKey = datDay.Format(_T("%Y-%m-%d"));

        if (m_pMapSPtrEvents != nullptr)
        {
            psEvent = nullptr;
            m_pMapSPtrEvents->Lookup(strKey, reinterpret_cast<void*&>(psEvent));
            if (psEvent != nullptr)
            {
                BOLDDAY(pDayState[iMonth], datDay.GetDay());
            }
        }

        if (m_Reminders.HasReminder(datDay))
        {
            BOLDDAY(pDayState[iMonth], datDay.GetDay());
        }

        datDay = datDay + spnDay;
        iThisMonth = datDay.GetMonth();
        if (iThisMonth != iLastMonth)
        {
            iLastMonth = iThisMonth;
            iMonth++;
        }
    } while (iMonth < iMonthCount);
}
```

Everywhere I use this `BOLDDAY` macro I get a code analysis warning ([C26481](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26481?view=msvc-160)):

> warning C26481: Don't use pointer arithmetic. Use span instead (bounds.1).

[image]

It is not clear to me if the problem is with the `BOLDDAY` macro or my own code?

---

#### Update

I still get the warning when I turn the macro into a function:

[image]

---

#### Update 2

If it helps, I currently call the `InitDayStateArray` function in the following ways:

- Method 1:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::SetDayStates(CMonthCalCtrl &rCalendar)
{
    COleDateTime        datFrom, datUntil;

    const auto iMonthCount = rCalendar.GetMonthRange(datFrom, datUntil, GMR_DAYSTATE);
    auto pDayState = new MONTHDAYSTATE[iMonthCount];
    if (pDayState != nullptr)
    {
        InitDayStateArray(iMonthCount, pDayState, datFrom);
        VERIFY(rCalendar.SetDayState(iMonthCount, pDayState));
        delete[] pDayState;
    }
}
```

- Method 2

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::OnGetDayStateEnd(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMDAYSTATE* pDayState = reinterpret_cast<NMDAYSTATE*>(pNMHDR);
    MONTHDAYSTATE   mdState[3]{}; // 1 = prev 2 = curr 3 = next
    const COleDateTime  datStart(pDayState->stStart);

    if (pDayState != nullptr)
    {
        InitDayStateArray(pDayState->cDayState, &mdState[0], datStart);
        pDayState->prgDayState = &mdState[0];
    }

    if (pResult != nullptr)
        *pResult = 0;
}
```

Perhaps if the container for the `LPMONTHDAYSTATE` information is tweaked somehow it would contribute to resolve this `span` issue?

Comment: @WernerHenze Here is the first question. I have added it on StackOverflow as suggested on another forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code provided by Microsoft used to be published as code that compiles both with a C and C++ compiler. That limits availability of language features, frequently producing code that particularly C++ clients shouldn't be using verbatim.

The case here being the `BOLDDAY` function-like macro, that's working around not having reference types in C. C++, on the other hand, does, and the macro can be replaced with a function instead:

```cpp
void bold_day(DWORD& day_state, int const day) noexcept {
    if (day > 0 && day < 32) {
        day_state |= (0x00000001 << (day - 1));
    }
}
```

Using this function in place of the `BOLDDAY` macro silences the [C26481](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26481) diagnostic.

While that works, I'm at a complete loss to understand where the compiler is seeing pointer arithmetic in the macro version. Regardless, replacing a function-like macro with an actual function (or function template) where possible is always desirable.

### Update

Things are starting to make sense now. While replacing the function-like macro with a function, as suggested above, is desirable, it will not resolve the issue. My test happened to have used `pDayState[0]` which still raises C26481 for the macro, but not for the function. Using `pDayState[1]` instead, the diagnostic is raised in either case.

Let's put the pieces of the puzzle together: Recall that the [array subscript expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator) `p[N]` is exactly identical to the expression `*(p + N)` when `p` is a pointer type and `N` an integral type. That explains why the compiler is complaining about *"pointer arithmetic"* when it sees `pDayState[iMonth]`.

Solving that is fairly straight forward. As suggested by the diagnostic, use a [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (requires C++20). The following changes to `InitDayStateArray()` make the C26481 diagnostic go away:

```cpp
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::InitDayStateArray(int iMonthCount,
        LPMONTHDAYSTATE pDayState,
        COleDateTime datStart)
{
    std::span const day_month_state(pDayState, iMonthCount);
    // ...

    // memset(pDayState, 0, sizeof(MONTHDAYSTATE)*iMonthCount);
    std::fill(begin(day_month_state), end(day_month_state), 0);

    // ...

    do
    {
        // ...
            {
                bold_day(day_month_state[iMonth], datDay.GetDay());
            }
        }

        if (m_Reminders.HasReminder(datDay))
        {
            bold_day(day_month_state[iMonth], datDay.GetDay());
        }
        // ...
    } while (iMonth < day_month_state.size());
}
```

A `std::span` *"describes an object that can refer to a contiguous sequence of objects"*. It takes the decomposed pointer and size arguments that describe an array and reunites them into a single object, recovering the full fidelity of the array.

That sounds great. But remember, this is C++, and there's a caveat: Just like its evil C++17 ancestor [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), a `std::span` is an unhesitating factory for dangling pointers. You can freely pass them around, and hang on to them far beyond the referenced data being alive. And this is guaranteed for *every* specialization, starting with C++23.

The other issue is, that addressing this one diagnostic now has several others pop out of nowhere, suggesting that `std::span` isn't good enough, and [`gsl::span`](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL) should be used instead. Addressing those would probably warrant another Q&A altogether.

Comment: That's odd. In my test I used the equivalent of `pDayState[0]` which does trigger C26481 for the macro, but not for the function. Changing that to `pDayState[1]` triggers C26481 for both. Let me see if I can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I do have a related question about how I am managing the actual day state data itself. But i did not want to bloat this question with details about that (as I use `InitDayStateArray` from three places with different `LPMONTHDAYSTATE` parameters.

Comment: I will tweak the question.

Comment: Would you prefer that I **remove** the extra section I added to the question or is it better to leave it in?

Comment: Seeing the call sites isn't vital, but still useful. I'd just leave them there. If nothing else, it makes taking about alternative solutions easier (e.g. changing the signature of `InitDayStateArray` to take a `std::span<DWORD> const day_month_state` in place of the first two parameters).

Comment: That sounds good to me.

Comment: I did not realize you had updated your answer. Thank you! I had to use `gsl::span`. And, I had to use `size_t iMonth = 0` to suppress a unsigned missmatch for the `while` loop. But now I get no warnings for this particular function. It appears to work fine!  Thanks again.

Comment: I might have to ask tomorrow about the `SetDayStates` as a separate question. The other 2 compile fine! Night.